# An efficient way to set the same value to an attribute for all entities in a django model

Tags: sql, django, orm

I would like to replicate this SQL command:

```
UPDATE Table SET fk = null
```

on a Django Model like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    fk = models.ForeignKey('OtherClass', null=True)
    other_field = models.IntegerField()
```

I know I can do in this way:

```
for obj in MyModel.objects.all():
   obj.fk = None
   obj.save()
```

but I have hundreds of thousands records, so I would like to do not call `save` every time. There is a more efficient way to accomplish this task? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update multiple objects using [update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update):

```
MyModel.objects.update(fk=None)
```